# While loop is showing time out error in sql

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @sql as varchar(max),@ID int=1,@maxID int 

WHILE 2155>=1       

BEGIN        

 SELECT  @sql= ColumnValue  from table where ID=@ID        

 declare  @table1 table(columnvalue2 nvarchar(max),id int IDENTITY(1,1))         

insert into @table1(columnvalue2)        

 exec (@sql )        

 update table set ColumnValue=isnull(b.columnvalue2,'') FROM table a jOIN 
@table1 b ON a.Id=b.id        

 SET @ID=@id+1        

 END         

SELECT distinct CID,Name,sorder,Locations,columnValue FROM table where isActive = 1 order by Locations,CID,Name
```

when I execute above while condition it shows timeout.Can any one help why the query is time out?

Comment: Because 2155 is always greater than 1

WHILE 2155>=1

Comment: This code `WHILE 2155>=1` seems really odd. Your loop seems to always want to run.

Comment: This is an infinite loop

Comment: Is it possible to change and run?

Comment: Given what you have posted the real issue is that you are using a loop. This could be done with a single update statement.

Answer (score 0):

First, `SET @maxID = <some value>`

Then, change `WHILE 2155>=1` to `WHILE @ID<=@maxID` or your loop will never end...

Comment: SET @maxID =2155 , WHILE @ID>=@maxID (1>=2155)

Comment: should be <= not >=